# HTML Form: How to remember text values of button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

If you have a `form`, type some text into it, and press the `Enter` key, whenever revisiting that `form` you can double-click on the input box and see the past text submissions.

I have a site that when you press `Enter` OR click a button, it should take whatever is in the text box and use it for data processing.

This works totally fine when not surrounded by a `form` but when surrounded by a `form` an you press the `Enter` key, it does not act as an enter button push, I believe it's being overridden by the `form`.

My goal is to have the user be able to press the `Enter` key as well as click the button to submit the data, but to also remember the text values that were in the text box regardless of which way you submitted the data.

What I have:

```
<input type="text" id="username-field" class="form-control" placeholder="username">
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="get-name" value="Get Name">
```

Javascript

```
$("#get-name").click(function() {
    var name = $("#username-field").val();
    // ... call other function with name ...
});
$("#get-name").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var name = $("#username-field").val();
        // ... call other function with name ...
    }
");
```

What I would like to use:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" id="username-field" class="form-control" placeholder="username">
</form>
```

I tried doing `e.preventDefault()` when the `Enter` key is pressed, but this does not remember the text in the input field.

I also considered doing a small cache type thing but am unsure of how I'd go about this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `localStorage`

Comment: Being able to see your javascript would be helpful.

Comment: Updated to try and help

Comment: Um, `$("#username-field").val()`, not `$("#get-name").val()`. `#get-name` is a button, when you trying to get a field value...

Comment: Oops, thank you, mistyped it

Comment: "whenever revisiting that form you can double-click on the input box and see the past text submissions" - this is a feature on Chrome (maybe other browsers too?). This isn't something websites have programmed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Doesn't use `form` at all. Just, why you added it, if you don't use it as intended?
2. You either mistyped provided code copy-paste, or have errors in yours script (the `$("#get-name").val()` mistake).
3. If you want to prevent form from submission, you should `e.preventDefault()`-it in submission handler, and return `false` from it:

   ```
   $('#form-id').submit(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       // do smth. else here
       ...
       return false;
   })
   ```
4. Saving/retriving data with localStorage for HTML5-supporting browsers:

   ```
   $(function () {
      $('form input[type=text]').doubleclick(function () {
         var id = $(this).attr("id");
         value = localStorage.getItem("form_xxx_" + id);
         // do smth. with cached value, ie:
         if (value != "")
             $(this).val(value); // put in textfield
      });
   });

   $('form').submit(function (e) {
      $('form input[type=text]').each(function () {
         var id = $(this).attr("id");
         localStorage.setItem("form_xxx_" + id, $(this).val());
      });

      ...
      // all other work
   });
   ```

*Note: make sure you don't put some user's personal data in browser's local storage `-_-`*